# How to compare two text files and removing the matching contents and pass to output in perl?

Tags: perl, file, compare

I have two text files text1.txt and text2.txt like below

**text1**

```
    ac
    abc
    abcd
    abcde
```

**text2**

```
    ab
    abc
    acd
    abcd
```

**output**

```
ac
abcde
```

I need to compare the two files and remove the content from `text1` when there is a match in the second file.

I want the code in Perl. Currently I am trying the below code.

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open (GEN, "text1.txt") || die ("cannot open general.txt");
open (SEA, "text2.txt") || die ("cannot open search.txt");
open (OUT,">> output.txt") || die ("cannot open intflist.txt");
open (LOG, ">> logfile.txt");

undef $/;
foreach (<GEN>) {

  my $gen = $_;
  chomp ($gen);
  print LOG $gen;

  foreach (<SEA>) {

    my $sea = $_;
    chomp($sea);
    print LOG $sea;

    if($gen ne $sea) {
      print OUT $gen;
    }
  }
}
```

In this I am getting all content from `text1`, not the unmatched content. Please help me out.

Comment: Match in the position (line number) or anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should read the text2 in an array and then in the second foreach on that array use the array.

```
@b = <SEA>;
```

Or else in the second loop the file pointer would be at the end already

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

$\="\n";

open my $fh1, '<', 'file1' or die $!;
open my $fh2, '<', 'file2' or die $!;
open my $out, '>', 'file3' or die $!;

chomp(my @arr1=<$fh1>);
chomp(my @arr2=<$fh2>);

foreach my $x (@arr1){
        print $out $x if (!grep (/^\Q$x\E$/,@arr2));
}

close $fh1;
close $fh2;
close $out;
```

After executing the above, the file 'file3' contains:

```
$ cat file3
ac
abcde
```

Comment: There's no point in closing the files at the end of the program unless you want to handle any errors. Perl will tidy up for you.

Comment: Working only if the files are small enough to fit into memory

Comment: I have tried this approach i am not able to delete the lines with special characters like i have a line with lost+found in both the text files so it should not come to output file but it is not happening so . apart from this every thing is working fine thanks @guru

Comment: @Guru can you please help me as i am very fresh to this scripting language i tried couple of things but it is not succesful .

Answer (score 1):

This is my plan:

1. Read the contents of first file in a hash, with a counter of occurrences. For example, working with your data you get:

   ```
   %lines = ( 'ac' => 1,
       'abc' => 1,
       'abcd' => 1,
       'abcde' => 1);
   ```
2. Read the second file, deleting the previous hash %lines if key exists.
3. Print the keys `%lines` to the desired file.

Example:

```
 use strict;

 open my $fh1, '<', 'text1' or die $!;
 open my $fh2, '<', 'text2' or die $!;
 open my $out, '>', 'output' or die $!;
 my %lines = ();

 while( my $key = <$fh1> ) {
    chomp $key;
    $lines{$key} = 1;
 }

 while( my $key = <$fh2> ) {
    chomp $key;
    delete $lines{$key};
 }

 foreach my $key(keys %lines){
    print $out $key, "\n";
 }

 close $fh1;
 close $fh2;
 close $out;
```

Comment: I understand your plan but i am new to perl that to hashes , can you please provide code if possible , thanks for your idea.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that you have undefined the input record separator `$/`. That means the *whole file* will be read as a single string, and all you can do is say that the two files are different.

Remove `undef $/` and things will work a whole lot better. However the inner `for` loop will read and print all the lines in `file2` that don't match the first line of `file1`. The second time this loop is encountered all the data has been read from the file so the body of the loop won't be executed at all. You must either open `file2` inside the outer loop or read the file into an array and loop over that instead.

Then again, do you really want to print all lines from `file2` that aren't equal to each line in `file1`?

**Update**

As I wrote in my comment, it sounds like you want to output the lines in `text1` that don't appear anywhere in `text2`. That is easily achieved using a hash:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %exclude;

open my $fh, '<', 'text2.txt' or die $!;
while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  $exclude{$_}++;
}

open $fh, '<', 'text1.txt' or die $!;
while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  print "$_\n" unless $exclude{$_};
}
```

With the data you show in your question, that produces this output

```
ac
abcde
```

Comment: actually i want to print lines from file1 which are not equal to file2 . i understand about $/ seperator thanks for that.

Comment: @Ramesh: If you understand about `$/` then why are you reading the files in `for` loops, which will only ever execute once?

Comment: @Ramesh: Your goal to *”print lines from file1 which are not equal to file2”* needs defining better. If `file1` contains `aa\nbb\n` and file2 contains `bb\naa\n` then what output do you want?

Comment: for example test 1 is having im23 , im34, im45 and test 2 is having im32 , im43 , im34 i need output has im23 and im45 only because im 34 was present in 2nd file . hope you got my point

Comment: So you need to output the lines in `test1` that don't appear anywhere in `file2`? That's easy enough.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to view your problem like this:

- You have a set *S* of strings in `file.txt`.
- You have a set *F* of forbidden strings in `forbidden.txt`.
- You want the strings that are allowed, so *S \ F* (setminus).

There is a data structure in Perl that implements a set of strings: The *hash*. (It can also map to scalars, but that is secondary here).

So first we create the set of the lines we have. We let all the strings in that file map to `undef`, as we don't need that value:

```
open my $FILE, "<", "file.txt" or die "Can't open file.txt: $!";
my %Set = map {$_ => undef} <$FILE>;
```

We create the forbidden set the same way:

```
open my $FORBIDDEN, "<", "forbidden.txt" or die "Can't open forbidden.txt: $!";
my %Forbidden = map {$_ => undef} <$FORBIDDEN>;
```

The set minus works like either of these ways:

- For each element *x* in *S*, *x* is in the result set *R* iff *x* isn't in *F*.

  ```
  my %Result = map {$_ => $Set{$_}} grep {not exists $Forbidden{$_}} keys %Set;
  ```
- The result set *R* initially is *S*. For each element in *F*, we delete that item from *R*:

  ```
  my %Result = %Set; # make a copy
  delete $Result{$_} for keys %Forbidden;
  ```

(the `keys` function accesses the elements in the set of strings)

We can then print out all the keys: `print keys %Result`.

But what if we want to preserve the order? Entries in a hash can also carry an associated value, so why not the line number? We create the set *S* like this:

```
open my $FILE, "<", "file.txt" or die "Can't open file.txt: $!";
my $line_no = 1;
my %Set = map {$_ => $line_no++} <$FILE>;
```

Now, this value is carried around with the string, and we can access it at the end. Specifically, we sort the keys in the hash after their line number:

```
my @sorted_keys = sort { $Result{$a} <=> $Result{$b} } keys %Result;
print @sorted_keys;
```

---

**Note:** All of this assumes that the files are terminated by newline. Else, you would have to `chomp`.

Comment: I tried this but i am not getting the all the results i have around 658 files on which 609 should be displayed but i am getting only 382 lines . please help me

Comment: @Ramesh Sure, but you will have to show me the exact code that failed, along with some input that makes it fail. I can't magically guess your problems from halfway across the globe… Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: @Ramesh Errr, where, if I may ask? The code in your question has *nothing* to do with my answer, and wasn't even modified since my above comment.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you tried to edit my *answer*. That is a bad place to provide more information on your problem. Basically, you did `print %Result`, but you only want the keys: `print keys %Result`! Or, with filehandle: `print OUT keys %Result`.

Comment: Sorry thats my mistake , btw i tried giving the print keys %Result but it is showing the same result as i mentioned i have 650 lines in file 1 out of which 609 lines are not having any match with the second file(contains 45 lines) . so my output should contain only this 609 but i am getting only 380 . that to i am finding the lines which are present in file 2 also

Comment: I am very sorry, there was a bug in my code that swallowed every second value -.- Please see my updated post for the fix: `my %Result = map {$_ => $Set{$_}} grep {not exists $Forbidden{$_}} keys %Set`. It could even be reduced to `print grep {not exists $Forbidden{$_}} keys %Set`. My apologies.

Comment: Thanks amon , Now its perfect really great to use this keys , can i ask you a last question i am seeing the result in random order thats even better for me just i want to know how the order will be arranged randomly by using keys , please can you explain me about the keys , where else we can use

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24025/discussion-between-amon-and-ramesh)