# Concatenating 2 lines from 2 files having matching strings

Tags: string, fasta

I am still new to Unix, however I am eager to learn it.. 
I have 2 files, some lines have some matching substrings, I would like to concatenate these lines into one lines, leaving other untouched. Here below is an example for that..

File 1 (fasta file):

```
>292183
AGAGTTTGATCCTGGCTCAGGATGAACGCTAGCGACAGGCTTAACACATGCAAGTCGAGGGGCAGCGGGGAGGAAGCTTGCTTTCTCTGCCGGCGACCGG CGCACGGGTGAGT
>551166
GTCGAGCGGCGAACGGGTGAGTAACGCGTGGATTATCTGCCCCGAGGTGGGGGATAACCCGGGGAAACTCGGGCTAATACCGCATATGACCGTGAGGTCA AAGGGGGGTCGCA
```

File 2:

```
292183  k__Bacteria
551166  k__Bacteria; p__Acidobacteria
```

The desired output:

```
>292183 k__Bacteria
AGAGTTTGATCCTGGCTCAGGATGAACGCTAGCGACAGGCTTAACACATGCAAGTCGAGGGGCAGCGGGGAGGAAGCTTGCTTTCTCTGCCGGCGACCGG CGCACGGGTGAGT
>551166 k__Bacteria; p__Acidobacteria
GTCGAGCGGCGAACGGGTGAGTAACGCGTGGATTATCTGCCCCGAGGTGGGGGATAACCCGGGGAAACTCGGGCTAATACCGCATATGACCGTGAGGTCA AAGGGGGGTCGCA
```

I tried to use awk and perl for that, but I never had them into one file..

I appreciate any help,
Best Regards,
M

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723333/how-to-compare-two-text-files-and-removing-the-matching-contents-and-pass-to-out) will help you to solve.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\([0-9]*\).*/s.\1.&./' File_2 | sed -f- File_1
```